# Weird behavior with checkbox in Asp.Net MVC 3 (Razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm suffering a very strange behavior with the checkbox helper (razor syntax). The sequence of steps are:

In the Index ActionResult I build the ViewModel that will be shown in the web:

```
var viewModel = new MyViewModel
{ 
    Field1 = service.GetField(),
    Field2 = otherService.GetField()
    Field3 = otherService.Class.BooleanField
};
```

The Field3 is "rendered" with:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Field3, new { @class = "something" })
```

When the page is loaded, I can see the checkbox with the checked state (when the boolean value it's true, surely).

When the page is loaded, the "OnReady" Jquery event is launched. In this method I call (via AJAX) an ActionResult wich calculates a price based on the parameters that he receives from the ViewModel.

Don't know why, but the Field3 parameter is 'false' although the value is true, and the checkbox has the checked state. After that, if I change any control that fires this calculation, the ViewModel that receives the method contains this Field3 but with the correct value (true).

I've been looking for possible interactions with this value, but I've found nothing and, as I said, the field is correctly checked when the AJAX call is made.

Thanks!

Ps: HTML retrieved with FireBug:

```
<input id="Field_Field" class="canRequestCalculation" type="checkbox" value="true" name="Field.Field" data-val-required="Mandatory field" data-val="true" checked="checked">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="Field.Field">
```

As you can see, the state is checked but the value in the hidden is false.

Information retrieval by AJAX jQuery call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Controller/PerformCalculation",
    data: $("#form").serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        //UI Work
    },
    beforeSend: function (data) {
        //UI Work
    }
});
```

As I said, the second time I execute the call the form is correctly sent with the value as true. If I use software like **Fiddle** or **HttpFox** to inspect the HTTP call, **the "Field.Field" is false although in the browser the check is checked!**

Comment: Be aware that `CheckBoxFor` renders both a checkbox and a hidden field with value="false", and they both have the same name. It does this because normally, checkboxes post their value when checked and post NOTHING when unchecked. Since only the first field with a given name is posted, the hidden forces the form to post 'false' when the checkbox is unchecked. Its possible this is what you're seeing?

Comment: Thanks a lot bhamlin. I've been reading about this but I can't understand how it can be related with my issue. Yes, the hidden has the "false" value, but the checkbox has the true state. Even it's visible in the browser!

Comment: @loChaos, can you show us how you submitting the data on ready jQuery event?

Comment: Sure Fabio, thanks a lot. You can see it now.

Comment: @loChaos - Did you find an answer to this?  I have the same problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How are you determining the checkbox's state in jQuery? I use $("#checkboxId").attr("checked") currently to get it's value.

Comment: Thanks Yarx. The information is retrieved by jQuery (form.serialize) and posted to an ActionResult method. So the state of the checkbox is determined in server side and is false!.